# Combine sets and tuples in calculated mdx member

Tags: mdx

I'm creating a member in an mdx query containing my slicer information and the last one is my measure. When I add a set to my tuple (for having multiple slicers on one dimension), i get this error.

> This function expects a string or numeric expression for the argument.
>   A tuple set expression was used.

When I add one of the 2 members of my set to my tuple, I don't get this error.

what does this mean, I don't really know what to make of this, fundamentally there isn't a difference between adding a slicer or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tuple is a cell. A set contains cells. A set cannot be one of the coordinates of a tuple, as the end result is not a cell (a cell is given by 1 and ONLY one member in each dimension, where unspecified members will be taken to be either the All member or the Default member.

The way around it is by creating calculated members:

```
With Member [Time].[Current Period] as { [Time].[2013], [Time].[2014] }
Select (... your query here ...)
Where ( [Products].[My product], [Time].[Current Period], ... )
```

In the slicer you in fact have a tuple, as in each dimension a single member is specified. The fact that the member on the Time dimension is not a "pure" member coming from a dimension table column but instead is a calculated member has no influence.

Answer (score 1):

Without your actual code it is difficult to help you.

Anyway, from your question it seems you are confused with sets and tuples (e.g., you cannot add a set to a tuple). I would advise you to check a MDX tutorial explaining these basic concepts: e.g., the icCube [gentle MDX introduction](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html) should be fine for that.

Comment: Yes, this is the case, I can't add a set to a tuple, but I don't really understand why

Comment: A tuple is a list of members. A set is a list of tuples and not a member so you cannot add a set into a tuple.